# AngularJS - Dynamic <option>s not being properly selected (by default)

Tags: angularjs

In my case, the dynamic (provided or created through `ng-repeat`) `<option>`s in a `<select>` are not properly selected (like in cases when the `ng-model` has an init value).

```
<select ng-model="my-model">
    <option ng-repeat="n in numbers" value={{ n.val }}>{{ n.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AOYearntng4YAtYgKq3K?p=preview) to demonstrate my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the ng-options directive on the select element instead of doing an ng-repeat.

```
<select ng-model="model2" ng-init="model2 = '3'" ng-options="n.value as n.name for n in numbers">
  <option value="">Select an option..</option>
</select>
```

instead of

```
<select ng-model="model2" ng-init="model2 = '3'">
  <option value="">Select an option..</option>
  <option ng-repeat="n in numbers" value="{{ n.value }}"> {{ n.name }} </option>
</select>
```

source: [select directive doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

updated plunkr: [ng-options plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EywENoL1XZwzvchP9Eq8?p=preview)

EDIT:
If you really want to keep your ng-repeat, you can add additional markup to make it work:

```
<select ng-model="model2" ng-init="model2 = '3'">
  <option value="">Select an option..</option>
  <option ng-repeat="n in numbers" value="{{ n.value }}" ng-selected="n.value == model2"> {{ n.name }} </option>
</select>
```

updated plunkr: [ng-repeat plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KLMk2OslAVBwpQBa3hlt?p=preview)

Regards,
Camusensei

Comment: Arigato, camusensei *bow*. By the way, when (in which version) was `ng-selected` added?